# DocuSign Require Signing Document Twice with Different Tabs

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

I have a document that is using tabs to fill a document. The document is signed before and after completion of a task. Is it possible to modify tabs on an envelope - then re-generate an `DocuSign_eSign::RecipientViewRequest` (still having the initial signature / fields)?

Thus far I've been able to generate two `DocuSign_eSign::RecipientViewRequest`, but cannot figure out how to change the tabs in between signing:

```
PRE_SIGNER = 'pre_signer'
POST_SIGNER = 'post_signer'
PRIVATE_KEY = CREDENTIALS['private_key']
PUBLIC_KEY = CREDENTIALS['public_key']
USER_ID = CREDENTIALS['user_id']
CLIENT_ID = CREDENTIALS['client_id']
ACCOUNT_ID = CREDENTIALS['account_id']
BASE_URL = CREDENTIALS['base_url']

configuration = DocuSign_eSign::Configuration.new
configuration.host = "#{BASE_URL}/restapi"
configuration.debugging = true

api_client = DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient.new(configuration)
api_client.base_path = BASE_URL

envelope_api = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopesApi.new(api_client)

pre_signer_text = DocuSign_eSign::Text.new
pre_signer_text.value = 'Alpha'
pre_signer_text.tab_label = 'pre_value'

pre_signer = DocuSign_eSign::Signer.new
pre_signer.role_name = PRE_SIGNER
pre_signer.client_user_id = PRE_SIGNER
pre_signer.recipient_id = 1
pre_signer.name = 'Kevin Sylvestre'
pre_signer.email = 'kevin@fake.com'
pre_signer.tabs = DocuSign_eSign::Tabs.new
pre_signer.tabs.text_tabs = [pre_signer_text]

post_signer = DocuSign_eSign::Signer.new
post_signer.role_name = POST_SIGNER
post_signer.client_user_id = POST_SIGNER
post_signer.recipient_id = 2
post_signer.name = 'Kevin Sylvestre'
post_signer.email = 'kevin@fake.com'
post_signer.tabs = DocuSign_eSign::Tabs.new
post_signer.tabs.text_tabs = []

server_template = DocuSign_eSign::ServerTemplate.new
server_template.sequence = 0
server_template.template_id = TEMPLATE_ID

inline_template = DocuSign_eSign::InlineTemplate.new
inline_template.sequence = 0
inline_template.recipients = DocuSign_eSign::Recipients.new
inline_template.recipients.signers = [
  pre_signer,
  post_signer,
]

composite_template = DocuSign_eSign::CompositeTemplate.new
composite_template.server_templates = [server_template]
composite_template.inline_templates = [inline_template]

envelope_event = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeEvent.new
envelope_event.envelope_event_status_code = 'completed'

envelope_definition = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new
envelope_definition.status = 'sent'
envelope_definition.composite_templates = [composite_template]

api_client.request_jwt_user_token(CLIENT_ID, USER_ID, PRIVATE_KEY)
envelope = envelope_api.create_envelope(ACCOUNT_ID, envelope_definition)

pre_signer_recipient_view_request = DocuSign_eSign::RecipientViewRequest.new
pre_signer_recipient_view_request.authentication_method = 'none'
pre_signer_recipient_view_request.client_user_id = PRE_SIGNER
pre_signer_recipient_view_request.user_name = 'Kevin Sylvestre'
pre_signer_recipient_view_request.email = 'kevin@fake.com'
pre_signer_recipient_view_request.return_url = 'https://ksylvest.com'
pre_recipient_view = envelope_api.create_recipient_view(ACCOUNT_ID, envelope.envelope_id, pre_signer_recipient_view_request)
url = pre_recipient_view.url
`open #{url}`

puts "Continue?"
gets

# at this point I'd like to enter values for tabs...
post_signer_text = DocuSign_eSign::Text.new
post_signer_text.value = 'Omega'
post_signer_text.tab_label = 'post_value'

post_signer_recipient_view_request = DocuSign_eSign::RecipientViewRequest.new
post_signer_recipient_view_request.authentication_method = 'none'
post_signer_recipient_view_request.client_user_id = POST_SIGNER
post_signer_recipient_view_request.user_name = 'Kevin Sylvestre'
post_signer_recipient_view_request.email = 'kevin@fake.com'
post_signer_recipient_view_request.return_url = 'https://ksylvest.com'
post_recipient_view = envelope_api.create_recipient_view(ACCOUNT_ID, envelope.envelope_id, post_signer_recipient_view_request)
url = post_recipient_view.url
`open #{url}`
```

Comment: You could add the same person to sign twice, as two separate recipients that are the same person. You can generate different recipient views. You can set the routing order to be different. Only reason I didn't post this as an answer is that you may mean that you need to pause the envelope?

Comment: Hi @InbarGazit , thanks for the comment. I was able to generate different two different recipients + two different recipient views. Are you aware of how to add data fields in between generating a recipient view? I've attached what I have for API calls thus far in the original question.

Comment: you are using a template? in that case, why not have the fields in the template?

Comment: Hi Inbar,

I have the fields within the template. They are marked as readonly and I'd like to set the values. Currently I'm doing that for the 'pre' job fields using a `pre_signer_text`. What I'm unclear on is how to do the same thing once the envelope is generated. I won't know the `post` job field values until the job is finished.

Comment: you can add tabs using your code where you have post_signer.tabs, but if you want to modify existing tabs that came from the template then you have to create the envelope in draft mode ("created") and then make a different API call to modify the tabs and then a final API call to send it.
Another option is to pause the envelope and "correct" it.

Comment: Thanks Inbar, can you clarify the method for pausing / correcting? I wasn't able to find any examples of what API to call to set a tab value once an envelope is generated within the ruby client.

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-ruby-client/blob/c477b07c2f578214fdf7d0c5a33355f01e9a0b4e/lib/docusign_esign/api/envelopes_api.rb#L6132 update_recipients() method should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

You could add the same person to sign twice, as two separate recipients that are the same person. You can generate different recipient views. You can set the routing order to be different. Only reason I didn't post this as an answer is that you may mean that you need to pause the envelope?

you can add tabs using your code where you have post_signer.tabs, but if you want to modify existing tabs that came from the template then you have to create the envelope in draft mode ("created") and then make a different API call to modify the tabs and then a final API call to send it. Another option is to pause the envelope and "correct" it.

[Pause envelope workflow code examples](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/pause-workflow/)

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-ruby-client/blob/c477b07c2f578214fdf7d0c5a33355f01e9a0b4e/lib/docusign_esign/api/envelopes_api.rb#L6132 update_recipients() method should do the trick...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Inbar. I'm stuck on the `update_recipients` call. How can it be used to set tabs? I've tried building a new `DocuSign_eSign::Recipients` - then setting the `post_signer` on the `signers` with a `text_tabs` value set, but that doesn't appear to work. This is the body being sent in DEBUG mode:

`{"signers":[{"clientUserId":"post_signer","email":"kevin@fake.com","name":"Kevin Sylvestre","recipientId":2,"roleName":"post_signer","tabs":{"textTabs":[{"tabLabel":"post_value","value":"Omega"}]}}]}`

Comment: first, no roleName for this endpoint, this is only used when you have a new envelope and  using a template

Comment: second, is this a new tab you are adding, or trying to update an existing tab?

Comment: Hi Inbar, this is a new tab that I'm trying to add.

Comment: Modified to not send a `roleName`:

`{"signers":[{"clientUserId":"post_signer","email":"kevin@fake.com","name":"Kevin Sylvestre","recipientId":2,"tabs":{"textTabs":[{"tabLabel":"post_value","value":"Omega"}]}}]}`

Not getting an error message. The response is `200` with:

`{"recipientUpdateResults":[{"recipientId":"2","recipientIdGuid":"d9cc6211-2a06-48fc-8db5-354641f0b025"}]}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235426/discussion-between-kevin-sylvestre-and-inbar-gazit).